# Filtering a list of strings with list of keywords using loops

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list containing strings that contain descriptions from a body of text that looks as follows:

```
stringlist = ['I have a dog and cat and the dog is seven years old', 'that dog is old']
```

and I need to filter these strings by a list of keywords that are located in another list:

```
keywords = ['dog', 'cat', 'old']
```

and appending each keyword to a row depending on how many times it is located in the string.

```
filteredlist = [['dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'old'], ['dog', 'old']]
```

I am splitting the strings in the stringslist and using list comprehension to check if the keyword is in the list but is not outputting correctly when I am looping through the keywords.

The code is working when I use one specific string to search for as follows:

```
filteritem = 'dog'
filteredlist = []
for string in stringlist:
    string = string.split()
    res = [x for x in string if filteritem in x]
    filteredlist.append(res)
```

The resulting filteredlist is as follows:

```
filteredlist = [['dog', 'dog'], ['dog']]
```

which appends the keyword for each instance that the keyword is located in the string sequence.

When I try looping through the keyword list as follows with a for loop the output loses the structure.

```
filteredlist = []
for string in stringlist:
    string = string.split()
    for keyword in keywords:
        res = [x for x in string if keyword in x]
        filteredlist.append(res)
```

Here is the output:

```
filteredlist =  [['dog', 'dog'], ['cat'], ['old'], [], ['dog'], [], ['old'], []]
```

I think I'm approaching this problem completely wrong so any other method or solution would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what your issue is. Is the `filtered_list` above what you want the output to look like?

Comment: the filteredlist at the top is the output i want it to look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write this as a nested list comprehension

```
>>> [[word for word in string.split() if word in keywords] for string in stringlist]
[['dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'old'], ['dog', 'old']]
```

Comment: Beat me to it :) You may want to use a `set`.

Comment: thanks! knew there had to be a nested list comprehension in there somewhere.